# How to read multi-line data from COM port into variables in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, serial-port

I'm currently trying to send and receive data from a COM port, and while I can successfully send data, I am having trouble receiving anything.

I am communicating with a 'Bus Pirate' to read and write SRAM values in some electronic equipment, and I can set the Bus Pirate to the correct mode, send commands and data that get written to RAM, then send commands to read from RAM, but I'm not having luck actually pulling that data into my batch script.

This is what I get when manually typing commands using Putty, I want to get this data into a variable (or a variable per line) so I can strip out everything but the 'Read: Hex values' to then use in my batch script.

```
I2C START BIT
WRITE: 0xA1 ACK
READ: 0x5F
READ:  ACK 0xEB
NACK
I2C STOP BIT
```

Here is my example code snipped from my batch script:

```
@Echo Off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_CNum=COM3"
REM Set COM Port Mode
mode %_CNum% BAUD=115200 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1

REM Send data to COM port to program into RAM
>\\.\%_CNum% echo [0xA0 0x0B 0x5F 0xEB]

REM Select RAM address to read from
>\\.\%_CNum% echo [0xA0 0x0B]

REM Request 2 bytes of data
>\\.\%_CNum% echo [0xA1 rr]

REM Try to receive data coming back from COM port
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`type %_CNum%`) do (
    set _COMData!count!=%%a
  set /a count=!count!+1
)

echo %_COMData1%
echo %_COMData2%
echo %_COMData3%
echo %_COMData4%
echo %_COMData5%
echo %_COMData6%

pause
```

This all works up to trying to receive data back from the COM port, where it just sits there with a flashing cursor.

Can anyone help me get this data into my batch file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's unexpected, that the FOR-loop stops, because a FOR /F loop waits for the complete command output, before it even begins to execute the loop body.
Using `type <COM-Port>` has no end, only if there is a ^Z (EOF) character

You could try some modifications

```
...
REM Try to receive data coming back from COM port
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type %_CNum%') do (
    echo Read: %%a
)
```

And

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
< COM3 (
   FOR /L %%n in (0) DO (
      set "line="
      set /p line=
      echo Read: !line!
   )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to get this to work.
I might take a look into using plink.exe as I can get the returned data to show up in the console.  

I just have to figure out how to read it into a variable and exit plink once I'm done..

Comment: What type of results do you get, wrong data, empty lines or no output at all?

Comment: The batch script just crashes. I'm probably not implementing the code properly somehow I think.